# Loss making business with high share prices?

Tags: stocks

I'm not going into detail over the company but...

Let's say you have a group with brands across Europe and UK and the 2 brands in UK are A. & B.

If A. is making massive losses each month but brand B. are sailing steady, how do the UK share prices for the UK part of the group still remain high?

Answer (score 1):

This depends very much on *why* A is making massive losses and how big they are in relation to B.

If the group has a history of successfully launching profitable brands, and A is a new brand that has high expenses (production, marketing, etc.) but not yet generating much revenue, then despite the current losses it can be seen as a source of future profits.

Or A might be established but currently undergoing an expensive remodelling that promises future success.

Or B might simply be a huge cash cow that funds the losses of A out of petty cash.

Answer (score 1):

Stock prices reflect future expectations of large groups of people, and may not be directly linked to traditional valuations for a number of reasons (not definitive). For example, a service like Twitter is so popular that even though it has no significant revenue and loses money, people are simply betting that it is deeply embedded enough that it will eventually find some way to make money. You can also see a number of cases of IPOs of various types of companies that do not even have a revenue model at all.

Also, if there is rapid sales growth in A but B sales are flat, no one is likely to expect future profit growth in B such that the valuation will remain steady. If sales in A are accelerating, there may be anticipation that future profits will be high.

Sometimes there are also other reasons, such as if A owns valuable proprietary assets, that will hold the values up. However, more information about these companies' financials is really needed in order to understand why this would be the case.